# How to remove value from Mapped Parent Object fields if related child records have been removed

Tags: apex, trigger

I have 12 custom number fields on the OpportunityLineItem, each representing a month of the year (Jan to Dec). In OpportunityLineItemSchedule I have a custom formula field that displays a Month based on the ScheduleDate field. The trigger below is working fine, however if I delete an OpportunityLineItemSchedule it does not update the related field in the OppLineItem to a null value.

```
trigger MapMontsOnSchedule on OpportunityLineItemSchedule (after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) {

// UPDATED: Must handle multiple children for a single parent
// Instead of a single OpportunityLineItemSchedule, hold a list of them
Map<Id,List<OpportunityLineItemSchedule>> MapMonths = new Map<Id, List<OpportunityLineItemSchedule>>();

// Have a temp list ready for looping
List<OpportunityLineItemSchedule> tempOlisList;

// Now populate the months map
for(OpportunityLineItemSchedule sch : trigger.new) {
    // Check if the map already has an entry for the parent Id (key)
    if(MapMonths.containsKey(sch.OpportunityLineItemId)) {
        // If it does, then update the list with the new value (so it will not override the previous value)
        tempOlisList = MapMonths.get(sch.OpportunityLineItemId);
        tempOlisList.add(sch);
        MapMonths.put(sch.OpportunityLineItemId, tempOlisList);
    } else {
        // Otherwise, we will create a new entry in the map with a list value of just the current iteration's OLIS
        tempOlisList = new List<OpportunityLineItemSchedule>();
        tempOlisList.add(sch);
        MapMonths.put(sch.OpportunityLineItemId, tempOlisList);
    }
}

//List of OpportunityLineItems to update   
List<OpportunityLineItem> OppLineItemList = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
for(OpportunityLineItem oli:[
    Select id, January__c,February__c, March__c, April__c, May__c, June__c, July__c, August__c, September__c, October__c, November__c,December__c 
    From OpportunityLineItem 
    Where Id IN :MapMonths.Keyset()
]) {
    // Then, the following is the updated if statement inside your for loop
    if(MapMonths.containsKey(oli.id)) {

        // UPDATE: Because we have a list of children now, we will need to loop through all of them to assign values to each month before moving on to the next Opportunity Line Item
        // Create a for loop to go through the list of children
        for(OpportunityLineItemSchedule olis : MapMonths.get(oli.id)) {

            // Create a switch statement to check what value is the Month
            switch on olis.Month__c {
                // If the opportunity line item schedule's Month field was January
                when 'January' {
                    // Then assign the opportunity line item's January field to the opportunity line item schedule's quantity
                    oli.January__c = olis.Quantity;
                }
                when 'February' {
                    oli.February__c = olis.Quantity;
                }
                when 'March' {
                    oli.March__c = olis.Quantity;
                }
                when 'Apr' {
                    oli.April__c = olis.Quantity;
                }
                when 'May' {
                    oli.May__c = olis.Quantity;
                }
                when 'June' {
                    oli.June__c = olis.Quantity;
                }
                when 'July' {
                    oli.July__c = olis.Quantity;
                }
                when 'August' {
                    oli.August__c = olis.Quantity;
                }
                when 'September' {
                    oli.September__c = olis.Quantity;
                }
                when 'October' {
                    oli.October__c = olis.Quantity;
                }
                when 'November' {
                    oli.November__c = olis.Quantity;
                }
                when 'December' {
                    oli.December__c = olis.Quantity;
                }
                // If it did not find any matches
                when else {

                    // EDIT: do not put anything here for now
                    // You can leave this empty or put something in here to handle cases where the Month field is NOT the name of the month
                    // e.g. Month field was for some reason populated with 'Apple'
                }
            }
        }
        OppLineItemList.add(oli);
    }
}
update OppLineItemList;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not get `Trigger.new` in `after delete` ([Trigger context variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm)). So, you should consider using `Trigger.old` in delete context.

Also, You can minimize the code as below:

1. There is no need of `tempOlisList` as you can directly implement `for` logic for loading `MapMonths`
2. Check below code:

   ```
   Account acc = new Account(Name='Test');
   insert acc;
   ```

This is same as:

```
    Account acc = new Account();
    acc.put('Name','Test');
    insert acc;
```

---

Updated code:

```
trigger MapMontsOnSchedule on OpportunityLineItemSchedule (after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) {

    Map<Id,List<OpportunityLineItemSchedule>> MapMonths = new Map<Id, List<OpportunityLineItemSchedule>>();
    List<OpportunityLineItemSchedule> targetOlis = Trigger.isDelete ? Trigger.old : Trigger.new;

    for(OpportunityLineItemSchedule sch : targetOlis) {
        if(!MapMonths.containsKey(sch.OpportunityLineItemId)) {
            MapMonths.put(sch.OpportunityLineItemId, new List<OpportunityLineItemSchedule>());
        }
        MapMonths.get(sch.OpportunityLineItemId).add(sch);
    }

    List<OpportunityLineItem> OppLineItemList = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
    for(OpportunityLineItem oli:[
        Select id, January__c,February__c, March__c, April__c, May__c, June__c, July__c, August__c, September__c, October__c, November__c,December__c 
        From OpportunityLineItem 
        Where Id IN :MapMonths.Keyset()
    ]) {
        for(OpportunityLineItemSchedule olis : MapMonths.get(oli.id)) {
            if(Trigger.isDelete) oli.put(olis.Month__c+'__c', null);
            else oli.put(olis.Month__c+'__c', olis.Quantity);
        }
        OppLineItemList.add(oli);
    }
    update OppLineItemList;  
}
```